# Get more dates from a base date in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a date in this format - 20230926 (yyyymmdd).

whatever date I get at runtime I want to have dates till next 120 days in an array. For example If I get date 20230926. Then my final array should contain date from today till next 120 days. Means final array will have 120 records.

```
  finalArray = [26-09-2023,27-09-2023,28-09-2023.
   
    .etc till next 120 days]
```

. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop to iterate through a date object. For each step, increment the date by 1.

```js
const now = new Date();
const daysInFuture = 120;
const dates = getDatesInRange(now, daysInFuture);
const expectedEndDate = getFutureDate(now, daysInFuture - 1); // Exclusive

console.log(expectedEndDate.toString() === dates[dates.length - 1].toString());
console.log(dates.length === 120);
console.log(dates); // Show all the dates

function getDatesInRange(startDate, count) {
  const results = [], currDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    results.push(new Date(currDate.getTime()));
    currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return results;
}

function getFutureDate(relativeDate, days) {
  const result = new Date(relativeDate.getTime());
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getDate()` to get the **current date** and increment days and set using `setDate()`. You have to do it upto 120 times to reach your limit.

To deal with **Local** time,

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
const nextDates = [];
const dateLimit = 120;

for(let i = 1; i <= dateLimit; i++){
  const tempDate = new Date();
  tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + i);
  nextDates.push(tempDate);
}

console.log(nextDates)
```

For **UTC** operations, Use

```
tempDate.setUTCDate(tempDate.getUTCDate() + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

- convert your `20230926` to a Date object with regex parsing
- create an array and map its indices to days from the start date
- format the dates to your desired format:

```js
const input='20230926';
const length = 120;

const [, y, m, d] = input.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
const from = new Date(y, m - 1, d, 0, 0, 0, 0);
from.setMinutes(from.getMinutes() - from.getTimezoneOffset());

const pad = num => num.toString().padStart(2, '0');

const result = Array.from({length}, (_, i, dt = new Date(from)) => 
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + i) && 
    `${pad(dt.getDate())}-${pad(dt.getMonth() + 1)}-${dt.getFullYear()}`);

console.log(result);
```